# spring security Rest API error -403 forbidden

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Im using Spring security on a spring boot project, and Im trying to use a endpoint of my controller, but when i make the call from my js, I get the error: 403 forbidden.

My SecurityConfig:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login/")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/inicio/")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login/")
            .permitAll();
}

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws    Exception   {
      auth
          .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

}
```

My controller endpoint:

```
 @RequestMapping( value="/getUsuarios")
 @ResponseBody
public UsuarioTo getUsuarios( Model model) throws Exception {
    UsuarioTo to = getTo();

    try
    {
        to.setListaUsuario(usuarioRepository.findAll());
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new  Exception("Error al obtener los usuarios "+e.getMessage() );
    }


    return to;
}
```

My Ajax call:

```
function getUsers(callback)
 {

  var posting = $.post( Endpoint +'getUsuarios', function(data) {

   if (callback)callback(data.listaUsuario);
})
  .done(function() {

  })
  .fail(function(ex) {
    message("error","ocurrio un error al obtener los usuarios:"    +ex.status+ ex.statusText+ ex.responseJSON.error);

  })
  .always(function() {
  });

  posting.always(function() {
  });
 }
```

Comment: OK, did you send from authorized user?

Comment: Yes i did, I had to be logged in to make the call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either send the csrf token along with your request (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax) or disable csrf for this request.

As you did not configure csrf, the default setting is used so that the csrf token is required for every post.